# mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error

Tags: php, error-handling, mod-fcgid

I am get this error when request a page that the application try to get data from database:

```
 mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Platforms\\AbstractPlatform' not found in /var/www/vhosts/jonesandsacristan.es/httpdocs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php on line 38
```

Its is running on `debian` with

```
PHP 5.4.34-0+deb7u1 (cli) (built: Oct 20 2014 08:50:30) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

Do anyone can help me?

Comment: check this https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/16